# How to redefine a class with Byte-buddy to add an additional method

Tags: java, interceptor, byte-buddy, javaagents

If I have the following `Class` named `Dog`

```
public class Dog {
  
  private String name = "Spike";
  private int age = 3;
  
  public Dog() {}
  
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

How would I declare ByteBuddy for use in a `javaagent` to redefine the `Dog` class to provide the method `getAge` which returns an `int`?

The desired (effective) class should look like this below and be able to be invoked by doing `dog.getAge()`

```
public class Dog {
  
  private String name = "Spike";
  private int age = 3;
  
  public Dog() {}
  
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;      
  }
}
```

Attempt 1: I've tried changing the syntax to what I understand to be correct (PitBullInterceptor.class found below)

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
.redefine(Dog.class)
.defineMethod("getAge", int.class, Method.PUBLIC)
.intercept(MethodDelegation.to(PitBullInterceptor.class))
.installOn(instrumentation);
```

I have the following issue in my attempts

> The method redefine(Class) is undefined for the type
> AgentBuilder.Default

Which is basically a syntax error. I'm not sure which `DynamicTypes` or `MethodDelegations`/`ElementMaters` to use to configure the `Agentbuilder` to perform to this type of redefine/rebase as Rafael Winterhalter describes it

Attempt 2: I've tried using it with ByteBuddyAgent.install

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    ByteBuddyAgent.install();
    
    new ByteBuddy()
    .redefine(Dog.class)               
    .defineMethod("getAge", int.class, Method.PUBLIC)
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(PitBullInterceptor.class))
    .make()
    .load(Dog.class.getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent())
    .getLoaded()
    .newInstance();
  }
  
  public static class PitBullInterceptor {
    
    private static int age = 1;
    
    public static int getAge() {
      return age;
    }
  }
```

Produces the error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to add a method

Attempt 3: Lastly, I've tried doing so with the agent built

```
  public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
  
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
    .disableClassFormatChanges().with(RetransformationStrategy.RETRANSFORM)
    .with(new ByteBuddy()
    .redefine(PitBull.class)
    .method(ElementMatchers.named("getAge"))
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(PitBullInterceptor.class))
    .make()
    .load(Dog.class.getClassLoader()))
    .installOn(instrumentation);
  }
  
  public static class PitBull {
    
    private String name = "Kujo";
    
    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
  }
  
  public static class PitBullInterceptor {
    
    private static int age = 3;
    
    public static int getAge() {
      return age;
    }
  }
```

Produces:

```
java -javaagent:agent.jar -jar app.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class already loaded: class io.xxx.agent.boss.Agent$PitBull
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.load(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:363)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$WrappingDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:367)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:148)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:101)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:6317)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:6305)
        at io.xxx.agent.boss.Agent.premain(Agent.java:21)
        ... 6 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at t:\workspace\open\src\java.instrument\share\native\libinstrument\JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
```

Comment: What error do you get from each of the things you've tried?

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: Got it, thanks. I assume that's the error for the first attempt; how about the second one, beginning with `new ByteBuddy()`?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of [] allows for delegation from int io.xxx.model.Dog.getAge()`

Comment: As soon as you do `.redefine(PitBull.class)` it will load `PitBull`. You want to avoid that - but I have no idea how to do that with bytebuddy. (With a normal agent, I'd just install a transformer that does the changes when the class is eventually loaded. Or does nothing if the class is never loaded...)

Answer (score 1):

Due to limitations of the JVM, you can't add, remove or modify members of existing classes. You have to either

1. Add the method before the class is loaded, or
2. Modify the class on disk before the JVM even starts

Alternatively, you *could* use third party JVMs that do support that kind of modification (see: JetBrains runtime with the Enhanced class redefinition flag), but assuming this needs to run universally, it'd be a bit of a burden.

Comment: Wont using the AgentBuilder at the 'premain' entry point solve that issue?

Comment: @stackoverflow as mentioned, modifying it before it loads would work, yes.

Comment: That is interesting. I've tried that as well. Even using an agent within the premain the class still appears to be loaded before the agent can modify it. I've updated the question above to highlight this

Comment: As soon as you do `.redefine(PitBull.class)` it will load `PitBull`.